# Can't install anything using snap in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, windows-subsystem-for-linux, snap

So, I was trying to install VS Code:

`sudo snap install code --classic`

But I got the following error:

> ```
> error: cannot communicate with server: Post
> http://localhost/v2/snaps/code: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect:
> no such file or directory
> ```

I have no idea what to do, I even deleted and reinstalled snap, but the error still appears...

I did:

`sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd`

and then:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install snapd
```

It doesn't work!

Then I tried:

`sudo service snapd start`

The output:

`snapd: unrecognized service`

If I do:

`snapd services`

Output:

```
snap    2.54.3+20.04.1ubuntu0.2                                                                                         
snapd   unavailable                                                                                                     
series  -
```

With the command:

`systemctl status snapd.service`

I get the following, my system is with sysvinit:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). 
Can't operate.                                          
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

What is the reason this is happening? I'm using wsl2

Comment: The reason for `systemctl` not working is stated clearly in the error message. WSL does not run `systemd` as init process. You can take a look around in `/etc/init.d/` to see if you have a `service` script for `snap`

Comment: Thank you. So I actually added that part because of one comment in the `Ask Ubuntu` community, my system is from origin with `sysvinit` so it wouldn't work. I checked the `/etc/init.d/` and i did not find anything related to `snap`:/

Comment: @Panki I have the solution:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Windows WSL run these these commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/DamionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script.git
cd ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script/
sudo bash ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script.sh
# Enter your password and wait until the script has finished
cmd.exe /C setx WSLENV BASH_ENV/u
cmd.exe /C setx BASH_ENV /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Check the issues with systemd and snap in WSL here:

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2374

https://github.com/damionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script

Comment: Did not work with Ubuntu 22.04 ans wsl2. It broke my system. Had to manually delete the installed file. Instead, take a look at https://github.com/nullpo-head/wsl-distrod. This worked for me.